# Why does visual studio development server give 404 errors for some file types?

Tags: visual-studio, iis-express

I'm trying to test out visual studio development server and I get 404 errors for some file types.  For example if I have a file /Views/Users/SignIn.js it is rejected, where css are allowed. This same project works correctly in IIS Express.  I think it has something to do with allowed file types but I can't figure out how to enable them in isual studio development server. Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks